# Locked screen shows track name

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, media-player

Recently my Galaxy S7 started to show last track's name when the phone is locked. Even if the music player is turned off. How do I turn it off?

**Edit**
Looks like track information comes from any app: music player, Spotify, YouTube, chrome. Whichever app plays music/video last - it leaves a name on my lock screen.

Comment: Did you try clearing the music app data in the settings?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Settings > Applications > Applications Manager then find the music app, touch it then select Storage > Clear data

Comment: I have updated the question - probably it is system setting, not a setting of a single app

Comment: What about the launcher? Is this the default launcher?

Comment: Yes, everything is default.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Notifications > Don't Show

Blocks VLC, FBReader TTS, etc for Android 6, so probably similar on a Samsung ROM.